# C++ compiler flag vs. Yoda Conditions

Tags: c++, if-statement

In C++ programming, adding a compiler flag or pragma statement [assignment within conditional expression as an error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4706?view=msvc-160)

```c
#pragma warning(error:4706)
```

sorts out all programming mistakes such as this.

```c
if (a = b) ...
```

On the other hand, Wikipedia says [Yoda Conditions also prevents from access violation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions#Avoiding_some_types_of_unsafe_null_behavior), but it looks like that there is no reproducible case in C++.

Thus, are Yoda Conditions not needed if we turn on that compiler option?

Comment: Entirely a matter of preference. The newer convention is to make your assignments deliberate, as in `if ((a = b))`.

Comment: Yoda conditions don't help if `a` and `b` are both non-`const` variables.  Crank up your compiler warnings until your example results in a warning, then get your code compiling without warnings.

Comment: *"if we turn on that compiler option"* -- Wait a minute. "If"? You mean you would dream of compiling with**out** `-Wall` warnings enabled? :)

Comment: @JaMiT -- yes, absolutely. I hate playing dodgeball with compiler warnings. One compiler warns me that my function with an infinite loop and a return statement inside it might not return a value on all control paths, so I add a return statement after the loop. Then another compiler complains about unreachable code. More generally, part of my job is to apply my coding standards; I don't want to delegate that to some compiler writer who knows nothing about my code.